# Can dlmopen be used as a "drop-in" replacement for dlopen?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, posix, dlopen

I have a non-thread-safe *shared* library (C/Fortran), i.e. it uses global variables defining its state. So when I open this library multiple times from the same process using dlopen, the global variables are shared, i.e. the states are interfering (messed up) because only the reference count is increased. (My application works without problems when I dlopen [two physical copies of the library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864659/loading-shared-library-twice)).

I found the issue linked above and another issue mentioning [dlmopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73133472/what-is-the-use-case-for-dlmopen-vs-dlopen) suggesting that I *can* load separate instances of the library (with their own global variables), which would eliminate the problem. dlmopen's documentation is hard to understand for me, but I gave it a shot and tried to open my library with something like this:

```
inline handle_type open(std::string const& filename) {
    handle_type h = dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, filename.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
    return h;
}
```

But alas, I got a crash for which valgrind reported an invalid read of size 32 (at 0x2833DE35: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so)) from a strange (seemingly innocent) location in my code (`a = &static_function;`), i.e. assigning the address of a static function to some function pointer.

So my question is: should dlmopen on one copy of the library give the same result as dlopen on two copies? Am I calling dlmopen in a wrong way? Or is there a fundamental problem with assigning addresses of static functions when I use dlmopen?

Comment: You can't use `dlmopen` and then expect the symbols to become "available" to code from the default link space. You will have to explicitly import the functions from the *new* namespace with `dlsym`. Also, `dlmopen` will also have loaded redundant copies of every dependency of that library, you better be aware of that.

Comment: It's likely that the non-thread-safe shared library isn't linking with all the libraries it needs to function (such as libc). When you load it into a new LM, the new LM also needs to load a fresh copy of, for example, libc to do the correct thing.

Comment: The manual is very clear: *The object must have been correctly linked to reference all of the other shared objects that it requires, since the new namespace is initially empty.*

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is: should dlmopen on one copy of the library give the same result as dlopen on two copies?

Not necessarily<sup>1</sup>.

> Am I calling dlmopen in a wrong way?

I would suggest using `RTLD_NOW` instead of `RTLD_LAZY`.

If you do that, and `dlmopen` call does not fail (does not return `NULL`), *then* you can conclude that this library has been properly linked with all of its dependencies.

If `dlmopen(..., RTLD_NOW)` fails, you can conclude that using `dlmopen` on this library will not work.

---

If `dlmopen` *should* work, your next task is to figure out the cause of the crash. Unfortunately, tool support for debugging this is pretty much non-existent. For example, Valgrind is likely to be completely confused.

You *might* be able to make sense of the crash using GDB, but even that may require manually telling GDB where the newly-added libraries reside (see [this](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11839) bug). Note: the bug has been fixed, so a recent version of GDB may just work.

> Or is there a fundamental problem with assigning addresses of static functions when I use dlmopen?

No.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are many differences. As one example, consider what happens when you call a function in this library (say `foo()`), which returns memory allocated with `malloc` and which you are responsible for `free`ing. When using a single linker namespace, there is only one `malloc` in the picture, and everything just works.

When you `dlmopen` the library twice, there are three! instances of `malloc` (one in the default namespace, and two in the two new namespaces). If you now pass a pointer allocated by one instance of `malloc` to `free` located in another namespace, a crash or heap corruption is likely.

---

I was also just reminded of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70043234/50617).

Comment: I don't quite understand why there would be three instances of malloc when I only call dmopen two times? Could you point me to a resource explaining this? How would I free the memory allocated in the additional namespace? My gdb version is currently 13.2 which should already have the fix (I've already tried debbuging with it). I'll try your suggestions, including debugging again.

Comment: "why there would be three instances of malloc when I only call dmopen two times?" -- you now have 3 linker namespaces, and each has its own copy of GLIBC. "How would I free the memory allocated in the additional namespace?" -- you would have to look up `free` in the corresponding linker namespace using `dlsym()`.